# Save output of bash command from Dockerfile after Docker container was launched

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with ubuntu image as a base.

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG var_name
ENV env_var_name=$var_name
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $env_var_name"]
```

I expect from this

1. executing of a simple bash script, which will take an **environment** variable from user keyboard input and output this value after running docker container. It goes right.
2. (part where i have a problem) saving **values of environment variables** to file + after every running of `docker run  --rm -e env_var_name=%valueOfVar% IMAGE-NAME` i can see a list of entered from keyboard values.

My idea about part 2 were like
`docker run  --rm -e env_var_name=%valueOfVar% IMAGE-NAME > /directory/tosave/values.txt`. That works, but only one last value saves, not a list of values.

How can i change Dockerfile to save values to a file, which Docker will see and from which Docker after running will read and ouyput values? May be i shouldn`t use ENTRYPOINT?

Appreciate for any possible help. I`ve stuck.

Emphasizing that output and save of **environment variables** expected.

Comment: try `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: What's the actual output you're getting?  What do you expect to be different in it?

Comment: @DavidMaze for instance, while typing command i use env_var_name=hello, so output after running `docker run....` (i wrote command at question section) will be hello. my point is hello will be saved to some file. so file at the end will contain massive of typed variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @lojza hinted at, `>` overwrites files whereas `>>` appends to them which is why your command is clobbering the file instead of adding to it.  So you could fix it with this:

`docker run --rm -e env_var_name=%valueOfVar% IMAGE-NAME >> /directory/tosave/values.txt`

Or using [tee(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html):

`docker run --rm -e env_var_name=%valueOfVar% IMAGE-NAME | tee -a /directory/tosave/values.txt`

To clarify though, the docker container is ***not*** writing to `values.txt`, your shell is what is redirecting the output of the `docker run` command to the file.  If you want the file to be written to *by docker* you should mount a file or directory into it the container using `-v` and redirect the output of the echo there.  Here's an example:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG var_name
ENV env_var_name=$var_name
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $env_var_name | tee -a /data/values.txt"]
```

And then run it like so:

```
$ docker run --rm -e env_var_name=test1 -v "$(pwd):/data:rw" IMAGE-NAME
test1
$ docker run --rm -e env_var_name=test2 -v "$(pwd):/data:rw" IMAGE-NAME
test2
$ ls -l values.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 May  3 15:11 values.txt
$ cat values.txt
test1
test2
```

One more thing worth mentioning.  `echo $env_var_name` is printing the value of the environment variable whose name is literally `env_var_name`.  For example if you run the container with `-e env_var_name=PATH` it would print the literal string `PATH` and not the value of your `$PATH` environment variable.  This does seem to be the desired outcome, but I thought it was worth explicitly spelling this out.

Comment: What does mean /data:rw? Can i just use data or smth?

Comment: Here are the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only).  The `-v` argument takes 3 parts separated by colons (:).  The first part is the directory to mount (in this case your current directory).  The second is the path to mount it onto in the container (I chose `/data` -- you could do something else).  The third part is a comma-separated list of options, in this case `rw` which mounts the volume in read-write mode (as opposed to say, `ro` for read-only).